# post request to external server and get Json back using Jquery

Tags: jquery, django, post, external

So,
I don't know how to do it.
I want so send some data via post to an external server and the get some Json back using jQuery. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Why don't you [search for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+post+data+json)?

Comment: [Funny thing is, if i search in google for exactly same question i am getting great answer at 4th position.](https://www.google.com/search?q=post+request+to+external+server+and+get+Json+back+using+Jquery)

Comment: I was told by a friend that you can't get data back if you use $.post for connection with external server(not the one sending me the html)

Answer (score 2):

Follwing is the example that i have personally implemented in a project.  
**VIEW CODE:**

```
        var ConsVal = $("#DropDownList_Constituency").val();
        var pollingDatalink = '<%: Url.Action("getConstituencyData", "Home") %>';
        $.ajax({
            url: pollingDatalink,
            type: 'post',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            data: { consitID: ConsVal },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#NoOfMaleVoters").html(data[0].VOTERS_M_TOTAL == null ? 0 : data[0].VOTERS_M_TOTAL );
                $("#NoOfFemaleVoters").html(data[0].VOTERS_F_TOTAL  == null ? 0 : data[0].VOTERS_F_TOTAL );
                $("#NoOfTotalVoters").html(data[0].VOTERS_TOTAL == null ? 0 : data[0].VOTERS_TOTAL );
            }
        });
```

**CONTROLLER CODE:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult getConstituencyPolledDataXVII(int? consitID)
    {
        var total = db.CONSTITUENCY_NA_RESULT_SUMMARY.Where(x => x.CONST_NA_CODE == consitID.Value).Select(x => new { x.TOTAL_VALID_VOTES, x.TOTAL_REJECTED_VOTES, x.TOTAL_TENDERED_VOTES});
        return Json(total);
    }
```

For details please visit [jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/) and search for $.ajax() function.